# Importar ficheros excel en Python

Tags: python

Me gustaría preguntaros si podríais ayudarme o si habría alguna forma de solucionar un problema que tengo.

Estoy creando un código en el que necesito unir muchos ficheros excel, obtenidos de sensores. El problema en sí lo tengo "resuelto" ya que con "pandas.read_excel" se que puedo importar los datos que necesito pero a su vez esto me crea otro problema que es el que os vengo a preguntar.

¿Hay alguna forma para que mi código pueda detectar en una carpeta todos los ficheros excel que hay y me los importe? ¿Esto se puede hacer?

Mi código actual es:

```
import pandas as pd
     
###############################################################################
#Cargarmos los ficheros que queremos unir, es muy importante que estén en .xlsx
###############################################################################
excel01 = pd.read_excel('HY1.xlsx', sheet='Em50 "EM47095" Data') 
excel02 = pd.read_excel('HyP1 22sep.21-1120.xlsx', sheet='Em50 "EM47095" Data') 
excel03 = pd.read_excel('hydros1.xlsx', sheet='Em50 "EM47095" Data')
excel04 = pd.read_excel('Hydros 1.xlsx', sheet='Em50 "EM47095" Data')
excel05 = pd.read_excel('Ehydros 20210526.xlsx', sheet='Em50 "EM47095" Data') 
excel06 = pd.read_excel('EM47095 4ago.21-1037 HYDROS1.xlsx', sheet='Em50 "EM47095" Data')
excel07 = pd.read_excel('HYP1(2).xlsx', sheet='Em50 "EM47095" Data') 
excel08 = pd.read_excel('HYDROS 20210602.xlsx', sheet='Em50 "EM47095" Data')
excel09 = pd.read_excel('HYDROSEM47095 21may.21-0937.xlsx', sheet='Em50 "EM47095" Data')
excel10 = pd.read_excel('HYP1(1).xlsx', sheet='Em50 "EM47095" Data')
```

Como podréis observar, son bastantes ficheros (y me quedan muchos más por incorporar) y para cada uno de ellos tengo que cambiar el nombre del fichero aunque se mantiene el nombre de la hoja.

¿Existe alguna forma para que sea mucho más sencillo el proceso?

Muchas gracias por todo.

Comment: Tendrías que recorrer y leer los ficheros de ese directorio y almacenar los nombres o los datos que necesites en un arreglo o lista, para luego cargar los nombres de forma dinámica de la manera que lo haces. Para recorrer los ficheros que se encuentran en un directorio puedes leer el siguiente tutorial en PHP. [Recorrer ficheros de un directorio](https://blog.trescomatres.com/2012/01/ejemplos-php-recorrer-ficheros-de-un-directorio/) Espero que te sea de utilidad.

Comment: Puedes recorrer el directorio como mencionaron previamente y hacer un filtro por extensión lo puedes ver acá https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3964681/find-all-files-in-a-directory-with-extension-txt-in-python?rq=1, si son nombres de archivos muy específicos puedes crear una lista y hacer un ciclo for para leer la cantidad de archivos que tengas allí especificados

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si los tienes en la misma carpeta que el script puedes listarlos con:

```
archivos = [_ for _ in os.listdir('.') if _.endswith('.xlsx')]
```

y, teniendo en cuenta que siempre es la misma hoja, leerlos sería tan sencillo como:

```
dfs = []
for i in archivos:
    dfs.append(pd.read_excel(i, sheet='Em50 "EM47095" Data'))
```

o directamente en una única iteración:

```
import os
import pandas as pd

dfs = [pd.read_excel(_, sheet='Em50 "EM47095" Data') for _ in os.listdir('.') if _.endswith('.xlsx')]
```

---

La solución de Dante es más completa ya que en la pregunta se hace referencia a que el nombre de la hoja puede cambiar.

Modifico la mía para incluir esa casuística:

```
import os
import pandas as pd

sheets = {
    'nombre_de_archivo.xlsx': 'Hoja'
}

dfs = [pd.read_excel(_, sheet=sheets[_] if _ in sheets else 'Em50 "EM47095" Data') 
       for _ in os.listdir('.') if _.endswith('.xlsx')]
```

Comment: ¡Muchísimas gracias! Es una solución perfecta porque utilizando muy poco código se consigue perfectamente lo que estaba buscando. ¡Muchas gracias de verdad!

Comment: @Mario tu pregunta dice "y en algunas ocasiones también el nombre de la hoja.". Perdon si ofendo, pero la solución ofrecida aquí no menciona como lidiar con el cambio de nombre de la hoja. Esta solución da por hecho que siempre abriras la hoja con x nombre. Podrías aclararme como solucionaste lo del nombre de la hoja?

Comment: @DanteS. toda la razón, no me di cuenta de ese punto en la pregunta y tomé como referencia las hojas que aparecían en el ejemplo. Debería estar como aceptada tu respuesta ya que la solución pasaría por establecer un diccionario en el que haya una relación entre archivo y hoja.

Comment: O aceptada mi respuesta, o la pregunta editada para reflejar el verdadero escenario.

Comment: Disculpad con la confusión. Realmente tengo varios pares de dataloggers registrando datos, y de cada datalogger recojo datos cada X tiempo donde cada uno de ellos me muestra un nombre de hoja distinto (según el datalogger que sea) y de ahí vino la confusión. Realmente yo quiero unir los ficheros por datalogger, por lo que con la solución propuesta la he aceptado, porque me funciona correctamente. Paso a corregir la pregunta para reflejar mi escenario. ¡Muchas gracias igualmente!

Answer (score 3):

Te doy una respuesta que tiene en cuenta la variación del nombre de la hoja.

#### Solución 1: Hardcoding

Puedes agregar cada nombre de archivo junto al nombre de la hoja (opcional). Para este objetivo puedes crear una tupla de diccionarios e iterar sobre esa tupla. Cada item de la tupla será un nombre de archivo junto con la hoja a cargar.

```
path = "."

files = ({"name":"archivo1"},
         {"name":"archivo2"},
         {"name":"archivo3", "hoja":"hoja 1"})

lista_excels = [pd.read_excel(f"{path}/{file[name]}.xlsx", sheet=file.get("hoja", "hoja_default")) for file in files]
```

Este código crea una lista de dataframes a partir de una tupla de diccionarios cuyos diccionarios tienen datos de cada archivo.

`file.get("hoja", "hoja default")` nos permite decir "si existe la clave `hoja`, devolver el valor que corresponde a dicha clave. Si no, devolver `hoja_default`"

Si quieres entender más sobre las comprensiones de lista (la forma que uso para crear la lista de excels), te invito a leer esta pagina: https://recursospython.com/guias-y-manuales/comprension-de-listas-y-otras-colecciones/

#### Solución 2: archivos txt con el nombre de la hoja a cargar

Esta solución, a diferencia de la solución anterior, no usa hardcoding y sirve para cargar todos los archivos de un directorio.
A continuación, agregaré el código explicado:

```
import glob
import os

path = "."

lista_excels = []

# Recorro el path "path" obteniendo todos los archivos xlsx
for file in glob.iglob(f"{path}/*.xlsx"):
    # le quito al directorio del archivo el .xlsx y agrego .txt
    # esto nos dará de resultado el path de un archivo txt con el mismo nombre y ubicación que el archivo xlsx.
    # ej: para el archivo hola.xlsx, el supuesto txt sería hola.txt.
    txt_dir = file[:-len(".xlsx")]+".txt"

    # si dicho txt existe...
    if(os.path.exists(txt_dir)):
        # abrimos el txt en modo lectura, obtenemos la primera linea y le quitamos el \n.
        # Esto da por hecho que la primera linea del txt contiene el nombre de la hoja a leer.
        with open(txt_dir) as txt:
            sheet = txt.readline().rstrip("\n")
    else:
        # si el txt no existe, vamos a leer la hoja default.
        sheet = "hoja_default"

    # agregamos a la lista el dataframe
    lista_excels.append(pd.read_excel(file, sheet=sheet))
```

#### Solución 3: Una mezcla entre las dos soluciones

Puedes crear un diccionario con el nombre del archivo a cargar de clave y de valor la hoja. Luego recorrer el directorio actual buscando todos los xlsx. Si el archivo se encuentra en el diccionario, se carga la hoja indicada como valor. De lo contrario, se carga la hoja default:

import glob
import os

```
path = "."

hojas = {"archivo3.xlsx":"hoja normal"}
lista_excels = [pd.read_excel(file, sheet=hojas.get(os.path.basename(file), "hoja default") for file in glob.iglob(f"{path}/*.xlsx")]
```

En este código usamos glob.iglob para iterar a través de la carpeta. En cada iteración le pasamos el nombre del archivo como primer argumento. Luego para saber que hoja cargar quitamos el path del nombre del archivo y lo buscamos en el diccionario. Si está, cargamos la hoja mencionada en dicho diccionario, si no, cargamos la default.

*Nota*: No olvides importar pandas